# How do i recreate this low quality camera, really zoomed in photograph:

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-quality, image-editing

How can i recreate this effect on my images?

[image]

I assume, i need some kind of chromatic aberration and making the resolution worse. i came up with something like this:

[image]

but it's nowhere near what i want.

The effect im looking for isn't really about low resolution but just low quality and the chromatic aberration's not the same. The picture i showed as an example of what i want is 568 x 425 px so it's not that small, i don't know how to express it but it looks like it's smaller than it is cause of the way it "presents the pixelation" and i don't know how to achieve that in editing.

Comment: The original looks like a photo of a screen image. Not a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

This is your photo as more inferiorized

[image]

- overexposure added by twisting Image > Adjustments > Curves
- old videotape or analog camera horizontal sync jitter simulated by Filter > Distort > Waves
- simulated heavy compression by saving as JPG quality = 2, reloaded
- heavy noise reduction effect added Filter > Noise  > Noise reduction, (this reduced also exessive already added simulated chromatic aberration)

Saved and uploaded to GDCSE

The noise reduction maybe is not heavy enough - not enough smudged areas. As another answer suggested, noise can be added. This is to get more work to noise reduction.

Answer (score 1):

With the image you provided, try applying curves like this which will increase all tones and blow out the highlights):

[image: First curves command, clipping the whites]

Then apply another curves command like this (which will bring many of the tones back down toward normal, but will leave the highlights clipped and will reinforce your chromatic aberration):

[image: Second curves command, decreasing all tones]

I applied a gaussian blur filter at 2 pixels followed by the unsharp mask at about 90% and a radius of 4.5 pixels.

After that, try saving as a low-quality jpeg.